# Combinatorial identity involving binomial coefficients.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

In order to conclude a proof (see last equality in [B. Poonen's](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/p-iteration.pdf) article), I need to establish the following identity:

> $$\forall (\ell,n)\in\mathbb{N}^2,\ell\leqslant n,\sum_{m=\ell}^n{n\choose m}{m\choose \ell}(-1)^{m-\ell}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1&\textrm{, if }\ell=n\\0&\textrm{, else}\end{array}\right..$$

I have no clue whether or not this identity is true, although I checked it on the first values of $(\ell,n)$, $(\ell,n)\in\{1,\cdots,15\}^2$.

Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This may be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/beautiful-identity-sum-k-mn-1k-m-binomkm-binomnk-delta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that

$$\binom{n}m\binom{m}\ell=\binom{n}\ell\binom{n-\ell}{m-\ell}\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=\ell}^n\binom{n}m\binom{m}\ell(-1)^{m-\ell}&=\sum_{m=\ell}^n\binom{n}\ell\binom{n-\ell}{m-\ell}(-1)^{m-\ell}\\
&=\binom{n}\ell\sum_{m=\ell}^n(-1)^{m-\ell}\binom{n-\ell}{m-\ell}\\
&=\binom{n}\ell\sum_{k=0}^{n-\ell}(-1)^k\binom{n-\ell}k\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-\ell}(-1)^k\binom{n-\ell}k=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n=\ell\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

and $\dbinom{n}n=1$, so indeed

$$\sum_{m=\ell}^n\binom{n}m\binom{m}\ell(-1)^{m-\ell}=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n=\ell\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

@Brian M. Scott

It is an immediate consequence of the product of the upper triangular Pascal matrix $P_n$ and its inverse. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix

Recall that the generic coefficient of $A=P_n$ is $a_{ij}=\begin{cases}\binom{i}{j}&\text{if } \  i \geq j\\0&\text{in the other cases}\end{cases}$

Recall that the generic coefficient of $B=P_n^{-1}$ is $b_{ij}=\begin{cases}(-1)^{i-j}\binom{i}{j}&\text{if } \  i \geq j\\0&\text{in the other cases}\end{cases}$

I will show it on the example of $n=5$, with an immediate generalization:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 &  2 &  3  & 4  &  5\\
     0  &  1  &  3 &  6  & 10\\
     0  & 0  &  1  &  4 & 10\\
     0 &   0 &   0  &  1 &   5\\
     0 &   0  &  0  &  0 &   1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 &  -2 &  3  & -4  &  5\\
     0  &  1  &  -3 &  6  & -10\\
     0  & 0  &  1  &  -4 & 10\\
     0 &   0 &   0  &  1 &   -5\\
     0 &   0  &  0  &  0 &   1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1 &  0 &  0  & 0  &  0\\
     0  &  1  &  0 &  0  & 0\\
     0  & 0  &  1  &  0 & 0\\
     0 &   0 &   0  &  1 & 0\\
     0 &   0  &  0  &  0 &  1\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\sum_{m = \ell}^{n}{n \choose m}{m \choose \ell}
\pars{-1}^{m - \ell}} =
\pars{-1}^{\ell}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{m}{n \choose \ell}
{n - \ell \choose m - \ell}
\\[3mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{\ell}{n \choose \ell}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{m}
{n - \ell \choose n - m} =
\pars{-1}^{\ell}{n \choose \ell}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{m}\
\overbrace{%
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - \ell} \over z^{n - m + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{=\ {n - \ell \choose n - m}}}
\\[3mm] = &
\pars{-1}^{\ell}{n \choose \ell}
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - \ell} \over z^{n + 1}}
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-z}^{m}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\pars{-1}^{\ell}{n \choose \ell}\ \overbrace{%
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - \ell - 1} \over z^{n + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{=\ {n - \ell - 1 \choose n}}}
\\[3mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{\ell}{n \choose \ell}{n - \ell - 1 \choose n} =
\pars{-1}^{\ell}{n \choose \ell}\ \underbrace{%
{-n + \ell + 1 + n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}}
_{\ds{=\ {n - \ell - 1 \choose n}}}
\\[3mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{\ell + n}{n \choose \ell}{\ell \choose n} =
\color{#f00}{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}
\ds{1\quad\mbox{if}\quad\ell = n}
\\
\ds{0}\quad\mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.}
\end{align}